# Getting a temporary processing output file path for usage in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am using a QGIS plugin which provides a Processing algorithm but does not know how to handle `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` as parameter value for its output. I.e. I have to provide it with an explicit file path.

I would like to use the same logic that QGIS normally uses when encountering `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT`, which is a new directory inside its current temporary processing directory.

How can I generate an output path matching QGIS' `QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT` logic to manually provide to the misbehaving plugin?

PS: A fix for the plugin is in the works but waiting is not an option.

Answer (score 5):

[QgsProcessingDestinationParameter](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsProcessingDestinationParameter.html) provides a [generateTemporaryDestination()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsProcessingDestinationParameter.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingDestinationParameter.generateTemporaryDestination) method.

As it is an abstract base class you need an instance of a child class, e. g.

- `QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination`
- `QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination`
- `QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination`
- `QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination`

For example if you need a temporary output path suitable for a raster file:

```
>>> dest = QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(name="foo")
>>> dest.generateTemporaryDestination()
'/tmp/processing_lcjJCe/052a1e8f2c7f43edaa72412b2e3f6c3c/foo.tif'
```