# Where should temporary files be stored in plugin development with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, files

I'm currently developing a plugin for QGIS, and was wondering if there was a recommended place that temporary files be stored. Currently, my plugin just writes to the `C:\Users\user\Documents` directory by default, which is not ideal, as I've recently had issues with it not being accessible, seemingly randomly. This causes issues as temporary files cannot be created, and my plugin encounters more errors.

Is there somewhere better and more accessible that my plugin could write the temporary files to? Is there a recommended/standard procedure for this? I've not been able to find anything online.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your specific use case, I suppose that the [QTemporaryDir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtemporarydir.html) class could be useful?

Comment: I'm creating a plugin that creates viewshed files as .tifs before inserting them into the project. With the directory I'm currently using, it seems to randomly not allow permissions to create these files. Thanks for that, I'll have a look into it. I'm also thinking of using the python tempfile library.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457091/getting-a-temporary-processing-output-file-path-for-usage-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

Preferrably avoid writing on disc, but if you cant I would choose a subfolder of your plugin folder itself. I have also done this once for a plugin. This way you can ensure the destination folder is present and until today noone reported an issue to me about missing write permissions. Just make sure you clean up the files as soon as they are not needed anymore (or regulary).

Comment: In the end I decided to use python's tempfile library to store it in a folder in AppData. I guess this would be suitable as many other apps store temporary files here too. Not sure if this is on the disc though?